# c# Httpclient multipart mixed boundary without content type

Tags: c#, httpclient, multipart

I'm trying to process a POST API call using `HttpClient`. But the program adds extra content type to the API request. Below is the resulting request payload

```
--myboundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

<User><FirstName>John</FirstName><LastName>Sinha</LastName><EmailAddress>John.sinha@mysite.com</EmailAddress><UserName>SINHA</UserName><Language>en_US</Language></User>
--myboundary--
```

How to get rid of the content type within the boundary. Due to this i get a `BadRequest 400` for the request.

In postman same request without content type works fine. Below is the code i used to create request.

```cs
        string clientId = "id";
        string clientSecret = "pwd";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://host.co.uk");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

        var authenticationString = $"{clientId}:{clientSecret}";
        var base64EncodedAuthenticationString = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authenticationString));

        string payload = "<User><FirstName>John</FirstName><LastName>Sinha</LastName><EmailAddress>john.sinha@mysite.com</EmailAddress><UserName>SINHA</UserName><Language>en_US</Language></User>";
        var myBoundary = "myboundary";

        MultipartContent multiPartContent = new MultipartContent("mixed", myBoundary);
        multiPartContent.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
        multiPartContent.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", $"multipart/mixed; boundary={myBoundary}");
        multiPartContent.Add(new StringContent(payload));//, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"));

        var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/api/org/2510/users");
        requestMessage.Content = multiPartContent;
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64EncodedAuthenticationString);

        var response = client.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
            string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed");
        }
```

[image]

`Headers.Remove` in the program is not effective or i'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: Maybe do `var content = new StringContent(payload); content.Headers.Clear(); multiPartContent.Add(content);` as you want the part without headers, not the multi-part.  Could it be the server expects `application/xml` as content-type and is that the reason your call fails?

Comment: @rene `Content-Type` header in postman is `multipart/mixed; boundary="myboundary"`. I tried the `content.headers.clear` that removed the content type from the payload. But still the API fails with 400. Tried with `application/xml` in content that too failed.

Comment: postman picture shows 12 header (other tab). Maybe you're missing a few?
Also: the postman request separates with newlines it seems. Your input string doesn't.